# Vertical alignment of form elements jumping when setting display to visible

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a form wherein on submission, if some values are empty an error is displayed. This is done using the following code:

```
<div class="form_input_row_container">
   <div class="form_input_half_width" id="form_input_first_name">
      <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" value="" class="errorable" />
      <div id="first_name_error" class="form_error_msg"></div>
   </div>
<div class="form_input_half_width" id="form_input_last_name">
   <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" value="" class="errorable" />
      <div id="last_name_error" class="form_error_msg"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

with CSS:

```
input[type="text"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="email"] {
  width: 100%;
}
.form_input_full_width,
.form_input_row_container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.form_input_full_width {
  margin-bottom: 20px; 
}
.form_input_half_width {
  width: 45%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.form_input_half_width#form_input_last_name {
  margin-left: 1%;
}
.form_error_msg {
  background-color: #f00;
  color: #000;
  display: none;
}
.form_error_input {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #ff0000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #ff0000;
}
```

There is some javascript that sets the html content of `first_name_error` and `last_name_error`and sets `display: block;` (it is set to `display: none;` by default).

[image]

However when this happens, the vertical alignment of the field without an error seems to go wrong (it jumps down).

[image]

Can anyone tell me why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: `display: visible` is not a valid value.

Comment: Apologies, just corrected it. It's `display: block`

Comment: Maybe display: inline-block could fix it. If you're using `.show()` display will be set to `block`.

Comment: Nope that doesn't fix it either.

Comment: it's because when you add the validation message, it stretches the size of the element containing your form input divs... you could fix it by positioning the error message absolutely so it doesn't stretch... or use `vertical-align: top`.. although your div would still stretch

Comment: What does the complete HTML look like when an error is generated. You haven't included the error's HTML in your question.

Comment: `vertical-align: top` did the job. Thanks. If you add that as the answer I'll accept it.

Comment: looks like someone else already took that liberty - although i guess the other answer only answers half of your question since you also asked "why"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs because when you add the validation message, it stretches the size of the element containing your form input divs. The default `vertical-align` will set them to the bottom.

You could fix it by positioning the error message in a way that it wouldn't stretch your container (I'd use jQuery UI's `.position()`) or you could simply use `vertical-align: top` on your form input divs, although with the second option your div would still stretch.

Comment: I think the default `vertical-align` is `baseline` actually.

Comment: it is, and that is what is putting his elements to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `vertical-align: top` to your input.

```
.form_input_half_width {
     /* ... */

     vertical-align: top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Uyhnf/2/